# Possible Permissions Issue With Wordpress Plugins on Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, lamp, wordpress

So I just fired up a new Digital Ocean droplet running Ubuntu 15.10x64 and I'm setting up a Wordpress environment. I am setting it up from scratch without a Wordpress image.

I followed a lot of the tutorials on Digital Ocean to get setup, and the site is running pretty well. I did not setup an extra layer of security with a 'wp-user' user and group because I was getting a lot of permissions issues when doing that.

I can upload images, etc. fine and install plugins. However, I noticed that the there may be something wrong with permissions for plugins. I am running Wordfence for security and a plugin called Backupwordpress for DB and full site backups.

Backupwordpress writes the backups to `wp-content/uploads/backupwordpress..` but when I run a backup it runs as if its completing a backup, but the backup never shows. When I check the `uploads` folder there is nothing there... No errors, nothing.

My uploads folder is owned by `$username:www-data` as well as the `backupwordpress` folder with the permissions: `drwxrwxr-x`

I've also noticed that Wordfence won't run any security scans, but again no actual errors.

The plugins folder has permissions of `drwxr-xr-x`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I use these plugins on a very regular basis (literally everyday) and have never encountered this so it must be my server environment. Also, are there any security issues I may have created while trouble shooting based on these usergroups and permissions?

Running a LAMP stack on Ubuntu 15.10x64.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this was actually a firewall issue, not a permissions issue. Opening up a certain range of IP addresses on UFW via the Wordfence support article fixed the issue.

The backupwordpress plugin seemed to work correctly once the DNS was resolved fully as well.